# Why isn't it updating

Tags: node.js, mongoose, api-design

```
User.update({_id: req.params.id}, userTemp).then(function(){
    User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(user){
      res.send(user);

    });
  });
```

So this code is running but it doesn't actually change the value in the database. I should replace the previous user with a new one however it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find out in documentation update can be used on document when you already have that document: [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update)

For your example I would rather use [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) like this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, userTemp, function(err, user) {
  res.send(user);
})
```

Comment: Cheers, your method is much cleaner; but it still isn't changing the data in the database for some reason.

Comment: Do you have any message in `err` parameter?

Comment: Also I have noticed that I have used wrong method in example `findOneAndUpdate`. It should be `findByIdAndUpdate`. I have fixed that in example

Comment: I'm a frigin' idiot. My patch request wasn't formatted as JSON so it didn't update properly as it couldn't access the variables due to them been treated as JSON.